# Make a form wider in size in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have created a registration form but how do you make it wider in it's size? It appears narrow on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Our forms are built to be responsive, because of this we set our form to take up 100% of the container width they are placed in when embedded. So if you have applied a specific size to the place on your page where the form is embedded, it will only take up that amount of space. We also try to use minimal `!important` tags in our CSS so any styles you have applied to your website will also be applied to your form.

We would be happy to help you look into why the form is not using the entire width provided if you would like to submit a support ticket.

Comment: Just want to add that the solution we recommended to Kellie in this case was to set the background color of her form to transparent so it would blend in seamlessly with her website.  This was exactly what she needed.  We had already decided to default backgrounds to transparent for new forms in our next release for precisely this reason.

Comment: Yes, the transparent background was exactly what helped my size issue, which was more due to the set layout theme of the website I was using. Nicholas was very helpful through the whole process, even doing a demo of a wider form on my site to see if I liked it. I had several correspondence over a few days time with him and he always answered my question the same day if not within the hour! Never have I had support like that!! Will for sure be using Cognito Forms for my other websites!